# addRule / insertRule Not working locacly

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

I am building a javascript image slider and noticed a problem pulling up the index.html file locally in chrome. Here is my code

```
(function(){ //slider container

    var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
    var figure = slider.childNodes[1];
    var slidyImgs = figure.getElementsByTagName('IMG');
    var figureWidth = slidyImgs.length * 100;
    var slidyImgsWidth = 100 / slidyImgs.length;

    css('#slider figure{ width: '+figureWidth+"%; }"); 
    css('#slider figure img{ width: '+slidyImgsWidth+"%; }");

    var xPos = 100;
    setInterval(function(){
        figure.style.marginLeft = "-" + xPos + "%";
        xPos = (xPos === (figureWidth - 100)) ? 0 : xPos + 100;
    },7000);

})()

function css(newrule) { //adds a new style to stylesheet
    var styles = document.styleSheets[1]
    try { 
        styles.insertRule(newrule, styles.cssRules.length);
    } catch(err) {
        try { styles.addRule(newrule); }catch(err){} //IE
    };
};
```

When i open the file locally, the insertRule doesn't seem to be applied. But when i open it on my server, the insertRule appears as normal. Anyone got any idea whats causing this

you can view the website /source code on my server: http://magnetwd.com/kellin/

Comment: I am guessing a cross-domain issue, but the only way to tell for sure is to remove your try/catches locally because right now you're totally suppressing any errors that may be occurring.

Comment: I am getting an error for styles.cssRules.length. It says can't read length of null. So Chrome is saying is saying document.styleSheets[1] returns an empty stylesheet. But why?

Comment: Not enough information to say for sure. I am guessing JS is getting loaded from a different host than the rest of the page... so the browser won't let you access. There's security implications here because you can find out information about the user by examining the rules. Why are you going this route instead of just attaching the styles directly?

Comment: I am doing it this way so my boss can add and subtract images from the image slider as he pleases without changing the css markup. His html/css skills are pre-historic and I want to minimize the chance of the code breaking on change.

Comment: ...but you can attach styles to elements without injecting CSS rules. Why are you trying to inject CSS rules? It's going to problematic.

Comment: not sure really. Should i just use style.property instead?

Comment: I would. Added an answer with a helper function similar to what you're doing now.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this instead (if jQuery isn't an option)

```
function addStylesBySelector(sel, newStyles) {
    var els = document.querySelectorAll(sel)
    for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
        for (var k in newStyles) {
            els[i].style[k] = newStyles[k];
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
addStylesBySelector('#slider figure', {"width": figureWidth + "%"})
```

Then obviously you can add more than just `width` for the second argument.